# regular expression not matching in c# but matching in regexr

Tags: c#, regex, evaluation

I found a citation parsing regular expression here: http://linklens.blogspot.com.au/2009/04/citation-parsing-regular-expression.html and it's working fine when testing it at http://www.regexr.com, however it's not working when attempting to use `Regex.Match` in c#.

This is the expression (with escaped \"") - evaluated from c# and re-tested in regexr.

```
/([^e][^d][^s][^\.]\s|\d+\.?\s|^)([A-Z][a-z]{1,},?((\s[A-Z](\.|,|\.,))(\s?[A-Z](\.|,|\.,))*))(\s?(,|and|&|,\s?and)?\s?([A-Z][a-z]{1,},?((\s[A-Z](\.|,|\.,))(\s?[A-Z](\.|,|\.,))*)))*\s*(\(?\d\d\d\d\)?\.?)?\s*(\""|“)?((([A-Za-z:,\r\n]{2,}\s?){3,}))\.?(\""|”)?/g
```

Would anybody familiar with regular expressions notice anything that may not be compatible with c# in this fairly complex expression?

Edit:

Link to regexr example with some text citations: http://regexr.com/3a232

```
        var myMatches = @"/([^e][^d][^s][^\.]\s|\d+\.?\s|^)([A-Z][a-z]{1,},?((\s[A-Z](\.|,|\.,))(\s?[A-Z](\.|,|\.,))*))(\s?(,|and|&|,\s?and)?\s?([A-Z][a-z]{1,},?((\s[A-Z](\.|,|\.,))(\s?[A-Z](\.|,|\.,))*)))*\s*(\(?\d\d\d\d\)?\.?)?\s*(""|“)?((([A-Za-z:,\r\n]{2,}\s?){3,}))\.?(""|”)?/g";
        var matches = Regex.Matches(TestApp.Properties.Resources.Citation, myMatches);
        Console.WriteLine(matches.Count);
```

Returns 0 matches.

Comment: What value/text is it not matching that you think it should.

Comment: could you post the regxr link?

Comment: Show how you use the regex in C# code. It is likely that you are using it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are escaping the quotation marks wrong. It's never escaped with `\""`.

In a regular string a quotation mark is escaped with `\"`.

In a @ delimited string a quotation mark is escaped with `""`.

---

You should remove the `/` from the beginning of the string and the `/g` from the end of the string. They are not part of the pattern, that is the syntax for a regex literal (which doesn't exist in C# syntax by the way).

Comment: `@""` should be called verbatim string literal in C# (or raw string literal in other languages).

Comment: Guffa, thank you - I've made the change however I'm still getting no matches.

Comment: @Sash: Another change added above.

Comment: @Guffa - much better... TA! :)